# Want Not Null and Default to False if Supplied value is NULL

Tags: postgresql

I want to achieve this:

1. column bool is not null
2. when supplied value is null it will fill in with default value `false`

thought this will make it:

```
create table public.testnull
(
    xid integer not null, bool boolean default false
)
```

test got error

```
insert into public.testnotnull values(2, null)
ERROR:  null value in column "bool" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, null).
SQL state: 23502
```

this will run but won't use `default`. Please don't tell me to use trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE public.testnull
(
    xid integer NOT NULL,    bool boolean DEFAULT false
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to use the `DEFAULT` keyword instead of `NULL` in your `INSERT` statement.

  - [From the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html):

    > `DEFAULT`: The corresponding column will be filled with its default value. An identity column will be filled with a new value generated by the associated sequence. For a generated column, specifying this is permitted but merely specifies the normal behavior of computing the column from its generation expression.
- Also, always explicitly specify column names when using `INSERT`.

  - Speaking from decades of experience: unless you're using an ORM it's impossible to keep your `CREATE TABLE` definitions and `INSERT` statements in-sync, and eventually you'll add a new column or alter an existing column somewhere that the `INSERT` statements aren't expecting and everything will break.

```
INSERT INTO table ( xid, bool ) VALUES ( 2, DEFAULT )
```

---

> Please don't tell me to use trigger.

However, if you want to change the `NULL` into `DEFAULT` or `FALSE` in a statement like this: `INSERT INTO table ( xid, bool ) VALUES ( 2, NULL )` then **you have to** use a `TRIGGER`.  There's no real way around that.

(You could use a `VIEW` with a custom `INSERT` handler, of course, but that's the same thing as creating a trigger).